# Почему display: inline не работает

Tags: html, css, inline, display

Почему то в моем браузере ( Opera ) display: inline абсолютно никак не работает и div-ы просто занимают всю строку

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #000;
  /*min-width: 320px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: auto;*/
}

.just {
  display: inline;
}

.inline {
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <ul class="just">
      <li class="inline">Новости</li>
      <li class="inline">Ураганы</li>
      <li class="inline">Холдинги</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: За такие имена классов руки поотрывать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри вашего элемента `ul` с `display: inline` находятся блочные элементы `li`, которые "распирают" строчный элемент изнутри до состояния блока. Это как в целлофановый пакетик положить кирпич. Пакетик примет габариты кирпича как минимум.

Если вам нужно выстроить элементы в одну строку, то задайте элементам `li` `display: inline`, как вам в соседнем комментарии посоветовали.

А если вам нужно чтобы весь `ul` был строчным, а `li` внутри него так и остались столбиком, то нужно задавать элементу `ul` свойство `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 2):

потому что применить нужно к `li`

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #000;
  /*min-width: 320px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: auto;*/
}

.just {
  display: inline;
}

.inline {
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
   <div class="main">
    <ul class="just">
      <li class="inline">Новости</li>
      <li class="inline">Ураганы</li>
      <li class="inline">Холдинги</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```